# Media image attribute empty in backend

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, attribute-set, custom-attributes

I have added a new media image attribute also added in the Attribute Sets but its not showing at all in the backend. Any ideas ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I recently had the same question, then i found this explanation: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6786

So "media_image" attributes do not create an input field or a selectbox. It's just a new role that is added to the image section of a product. So have a look at your product-images and the checkboxes there. Beside "Base Image", "Small Image" and "Thumbnail" you should see your custom attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Following conditions may happen:

1. If you have multiple attribute serts, then check in which attribute
   set you have added it?
2. Then check in which group you have added it
   inside attribute set.
3. Clear magento cache by `System > Cache Management > Flush Magento Cache`
4. Reindex indexes: `System > Index Management`

May be this will help you.

Comment: I did all this already but its still not showing. :-(

Comment: Never mind its showing in the images tab.